# Extract clauses from sentence in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have to list out clauses from given sentences. I am implementing my own grammar rules to parse out clauses from sentences. The result I obtained is:

```
*************************************************
(S
  (CLAUSE
    (VP
      (VP they/PRP were/VBD delivered/VBN promptly/RB)
      and/CC
      (VP a/DT very/RB))
    (NP (NP good/JJ value/NN) and/CC (NP excellent/NN)))
  (CLAUSE
    (VP all/DT)
    (NP (NP around/IN (NP slipper/NN)) (NP with/IN (NP traction/NN))))
  ./.)
*************************************************
```

From above result, clauses should be listed out, to give the result in the following statements.

`they were delivered promptly and a very good value and excellent`

`all around slipper with traction.`

I've tried using `flatten` and `chomsky_normal_form` but couldn't get the desired result. How to list out each clauses on single line getting rid of tags?

Comment: please post the code and the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Since all you want to extract from your string `s` seems to be lowercase, you can apply one of the following one-liners:

**Python list comprehension**

```py
print ' '.join(''.join(c for c in s if 'a' <= c <= 'z' or c == ' ').split())
```

It joins (`''.join`) all characters that are between "a" and "z" or " ". To suppress multiple spaces next to each other it splits the result and joins it again with a space as separator.

**Regular expression**

If you prefer regular expressions (`import re`), this even shorter statement yields the same result:

```
print ' '.join(re.findall('[a-z]+', s))
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to process each clause individually, you can split the whole string `s` and then apply the same code to each part (except the first one, which is just the header):

```
for part in s.split("CLAUSE")[1:]:
    print ' '.join(re.findall('[a-z]+', part))
```

Comment: Actually I want to list out each clauses on single line getting rid of tags.